# File extractall not working in python

Tags: python

I am trying to extract the file by specifying the directory name. But the directory in which i am extracting doesnt have the extracted file for some reason. The output shows that zipfile was successfully created but extraction is not done successfully.

```
import os, shutil, send2trash, zipfile

with open('C:\\Users\\aryan\\os.walk_2.txt', 'a') as f:
    for folder, subfolder, file in os.walk(r'C:\Users\Public\Downloads\coding'):
        print('*' * 60,file=f)
        print('THE NAME OF THE FOLDER IS {0}'.format(folder), file=f)
        print('*' * 60,file=f)


        for subfolders in subfolder:
            print('SUBFOLDER {0} CONTAINS FOLLOWING FOLDERS {1}'.format(folder, subfolders), file=f)

        for filenames in file:
            print('FOLDER {0} CONTAINS FOLLOWING FILES {1}'.format(folder, filenames), file=f)
            if folder == r'C:\Users\Public\Downloads\coding\Python':
               if filenames == 'anti_vowel.py':
                  zip =zipfile.ZipFile(r'C:\Users\aryan\python_files.zip','w')


                 zip.write(r'C:\Users\Public\Downloads\coding\Python\anti_vowel.py', compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
                 print (zip.namelist())

                 zip.close()
                 print('LOOKS LIKE ZIP FILE IS CREATED')
                 extract_dir='C:\\Users\\aryan'
                 os.chdir('C:\\Users\\aryan')
                 if os.path.exists(extract_dir):
                    zip=zipfile.ZipFile('python_files.zip')
                    zip.extractall(extract_dir)
                    print(os.getcwd())
                    print(os.listdir())
                    for folder, sub, filename in os.walk(r'C:\Users\aryan'):
                        for file in filename:
                          if file == 'python_files.zip':
                              print ('ZIP FILE STILL PRESENT')
                              #os.remove('python_files.zip')
                              if file == 'anti_vowel.py':
                                  print('EXTRACTED FILE IS PRESENT')
                              else:
                                  print('EXTRACTED FILE IS MISSING')

                   zip.close()
                else:
                   print ('THE DIR TO WHICH FILE NEEDS TO BE EXTRACTED IS MISSING')
```

OUTPUT:-

```
 ['Users/Public/Downloads/coding/Python/anti_vowel.py']
 LOOKS LIKE ZIP FILE IS CREATED
 C:\Users\aryan
 ['.idlerc', '.PyCharm2017.1', 'AppData', 'Application Data', 'Contacts', 
 'Cookies', 'Desktop', 'Documents', 'Downloads', 'Favorites', 'LEH2016', 
 'Links', 'Local Settings', 'Music', 'My Documents', 'NetHood', 
 'NTUSER.DAT', 'ntuser.dat.LOG1', 'ntuser.dat.LOG2', 'NTUSER.DAT{ac08763f-
 3218-11e7-8556-93c7ff812bb9}.TM.blf', 'NTUSER.DAT{ac08763f-3218-11e7-8556-
 93c7ff812bb9}.TMContainer00000000000000000001.regtrans-ms', 
'NTUSER.DAT{ac08763f-3218-11e7-8556-
 93c7ff812bb9}.TMContainer00000000000000000002.regtrans-ms', 'ntuser.ini', 
'OneDrive', 'os.walk_2.txt', 'os.walk_result.txt', 'Pictures', 'PrintHood', 
'PycharmProjects', 'python_files.zip', 'Recent', 'Saved Games', 'Searches', 
'SendTo', 'Start Menu', 'Templates', 'Users', 'Videos']
 ZIP FILE STILL PRESENT
 EXTRACTED FILE IS MISSING
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here:

```
if file == 'python_files.zip':
    print ('ZIP FILE STILL PRESENT')
    #os.remove('python_files.zip')
    if file == 'anti_vowel.py':
         print('EXTRACTED FILE IS PRESENT')
    else:
        print('EXTRACTED FILE IS MISSING')
```

If `file` is equal to `'python_files.zip'`, then it can't be also equal to `'anti_vowel.py'` without changing its value so it's always goes in the `else` part

Comment: Yeah you are right. After incorporating those changes still i dont see the extracted file in the destination directory.                                                   
                              if file == 'python_files.zip':
                                  print ('ZIP FILE STILL PRESENT')
                              if file == 'anti_vowel.py':
                                    print('EXTRACTED FILE IS PRESENT')
                                    print ('AFTER EXTRACTION:-','\n',os.listdir('C:\\Users\\aryan'))

Comment: the file after unzipping should appear in 'C:\\Users\\aryan' but it is not there.

Answer (score 0):

In short, I don't think your able to read compressed file contents beyond the container. First, I am barely starting software development instruction and don't know much of anything but I do get the gist of what your attempting to accomplish. Similarly, when I load my Music Software program--FL Studio--with audio files under compression (in zip files) the DAW see's the file object(s)--when dragged, the compressed file icon will interact with and trigger responses per the settings and produce visual changes on hovering (for instance) but when the loading status indicator completes, there is no track in the sequencer. I think perhaps what might be happening is that the IDE is not capable of seeing the compressed file content container and either some or all of the meta data but not the actual data text your defining and therefore does not produce the anticipated file. I understand that compressed files can be read from certain ide's like VS code with certain extension packages. Also, What Terminal utility is being used?